# Why does WKWebView call scrollviewDidScroll when initialised and how to prevent it?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, wkwebview

In a UIViewController, I instantiate a WKWebView and set the view controller as the WKWebiew scrollview's delegate:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var webView : WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view = webView      

        webView.loadHTMLString("<h1>hello</h1>", baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)

        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        println("didScroll")
    }
```

The problem I have is that scrollViewDidScroll is called as soon as the WKWebView is created (ie without the user actually scrolling anything).

Why is that and how can I prevent it ?

Comment: Explain what you are actually trying to accomplish. This is too unspecific.

Comment: If you dont want scrollview method to be called them just dont set delegate or dont implement scrollviewDidScroll.  but if you want to work with delegate either set it up or dont implement the method. but again as @StefanArentz said, please explain what are you trying to do. Sorry if I coming to party late

Comment: I get this issue too, a lot.

Comment: I'm not surprised about noisy scrolling messages while the layout is happening.  Setting the delegate in viewDidLayoutSubviews should get you past all that.

Answer (score 3):

Set a bool value to true in scrollViewWillBeginDragging method, which is called only when user scrolls and it is not automatically called by WKWebview

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    scrollByDragging = true
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   if !scrollByDragging{

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01) {
         scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a IBOUtlet for Wkebview I have the delegates 
 webView.scrollView.delegate = self but  scrollViewDidScroll delegates does not call what else is need to be done.

Comment: after adding scrollViewDidScroll my WKWebview scroll becomes terribly slow , was that the case with you , could you suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `contentOffset`, you would be able to detect when the user scrolls.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 {
        print("didScroll")
    }
}
```

If your `UIScrollView` is inside a `UINavigationController`, `contentOffset.y` will start at -44, but practically 0 is fine to use.